# Angularjs: Performance using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-class

This is a dummy coding that describes my problem
HTML

```
<div ng-class="{'test': isAllowed }" id='example1'>Example 1</div>
<div ng-class="{'test': isAllowed }" id='example2'>Example 2</div>
```

**$scope.isAllowed** is evaluated completely, and **#example1** is affected by the class **test**, but sometimes it takes time for **#example2** to be affected by that class, although both of them share same class. I think the problem is with **ng-class**.
 I can fix my problem using **ng-if**

```
<div class="test" ng-if="isAllowed" id='example1'>Example 1</div>
<div ng-if="!isAllowed" id='example1'>Example 1</div>
<div class="test" ng-if="isAllowed" id='example2'>Example 2</div>
<div ng-if="!isAllowed" id='example2'>Example 2</div>
```

As you can see, It looks redundant, and I don't want to deal with the problem in this way

Comment: code looks fine, can you create a demo to reproduce the issue ? and just a crosscheck, did you enclose **{'test': isAllowed }** in double quotes ?

Comment: It won't be a problem with a little code like above. **ng-class** will works fine. It's a little difficult for me to reproduce the issue with some codes.

Comment: You may want to add double quotes. ng-class="{'test': isAllowed }"

Comment: @Esaith, sorry, I've edited it, but It's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

How is isAllowed being set? If it's being set within a setTimeout, setInterval, or something else that is outside of the angular lifecycle, you may need to include a

`scope.$apply()`

(if its a directive), or

`$scope.$apply()`

(if its in a controller) after you have set the isActive.

```
$scope.isActive = true;
$scope.$apply();
```

If neither of those two work, or if you get a "already in a digest cycle" error, then wrap with an $evalAsync

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(){
    $scope.isActive = true;
});
```

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/cyx4z03m/1/ You will see that the css is not being updated except once every 3 seconds. Open your DevTools and check out the console log. The value is being toggled, but you dont see the real result until angular knows its ready to update. I'm wondering if your issue is related.